# How to get mouse location in NetBeans Visual Library?

Tags: java, netbeans, mouse, netbeans-7.1, mouse-coordinates

I want to add widgets by double clicking, so I've added *EditAction* to my scene and overrode *EditProvider*'s `edit` method. Now the problem is that I want to set initial position of the widget to my mouse position. I've found out that I can use

```
MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation()
```

to get my mouse's location, but it's relative to the screen. I've also read that people use

```
component.getLocationOnScreen()
```

to subtract parent's location on screen from the mouse's one, but my scene doesn't seem to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After creating a Scene, you need to use createView() (to create the view JComponent) or getView() (to access the already-created JComponent instance).

You can use your JComponent instance (after it is created) to obtain the component's location on screen:

```
scene.getView().getLocationOnScreen()
```